# Flex grow not using space when one of the children is wrapped

Tags: html, css, flexbox

In the following code, I would like to have the 2nd child (single line, never wrap) to use all available space.

In example 1, that works well.

But when the first child wraps due to lack of space in example 2, there is a large gap between the two children. How can I remove that large gap that appears only when the first child content wraps?

```css
.container {
margin-bottom:1rem;
background-color:#eee;
display:flex;
gap:1rem;
align-items:center;
}

.container>span:nth-child(1) {
  
}

.container>span:nth-child(2) {
white-space:nowrap;
flex:1 1 auto;
}
```

```html
Example 1:
<div class="container"  style="width:500px;">
  <span>text allowed to be multilineeeeeeee</span>
  <span>single line</span>
</div>

Example 2:
<div class="container" style="width:250px;">
  <span>text allowed to be multilineeeeeeee</span>
  <span>single line</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`flex: 1 1 min-content;`

This should get you close but note that it's just not possible to completely collapse the containing span when the text wraps. There is **always** space to the right on a wrap be it text or inline (or inline-block) elements wrapping.

```css
.container {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  background-color: #eee;
  border: 1px solid green;
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
  align-items: center;
}

.container * {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.container>span:nth-child(1) {
  flex: 1 1 min-content;
}

.container>span:nth-child(2) {
  white-space: nowrap;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

```html
Example 1:
<div class="container" style="width:500px;">
  <span>text allowed to be multilineeeeeeee</span>
  <span>single line</span>
</div>

Example 2:
<div class="container" style="width:250px;">
  <span>text allowed to be multilineeeeeeee</span>
  <span>single line</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't solve my problem since I have a mix of example 1 and example 2 in a list, so it makes it look strange to have some with little space, and some with a bigger one.

Comment: Then I'd suggest you demonstrate the actual problem in a new question but it's just not possible to completely eliminate *some* gap.